# Partial fraction decomposition trouble with a problem

Tags: partial-fractions

I have this integral:
$$
\int \frac{1}{(1+x^2)(1+(z-x)^2)} {\rm d}x
$$
and I want to perform partial fraction decomposition in this form
$$
\int \left( \frac{Ax + B}{1+x^2}  + \frac{Cx + D }{1+(z-x)^2} \right) {\rm d}x
$$
but I can't get the right coefficients A, B, C, D. Is this the right way to do it?

Edit:
My mistake was in expanding the brackets
$$
(Ax+B)(1+(z-x)^2)+(Cx+D)(1+x^2)=1
$$
particularly, instead of $Axz^2$ I arrived to $Az^2$ and then I was trying to solve completely dfferent system of equations.

Answer (score 1):

This is correct $$\frac{1}{(1+x^2)(1+(z-x)^2)}=\frac{Ax + B}{1+x^2}  + \frac{Cx + D }{1+(z-x)^2}$$ Reduce to the common denominator and expand the rhs; you then have
$$1=\left(B z^2+B+D\right)+x \left(A z^2+A-2 B z+C\right)+x^2 (-2 A z+B+D)+x^3
   (A+C)$$ So, you hve to solve for $(A,B,C,D)$
$$B z^2+B+D=1 \tag 1$$
$$A z^2+A-2 B z+C=0 \tag 2$$
$$-2 A z+B+D=0 \tag 3$$
$$A+C=0 \tag 4$$ which is not difficult.

Comment: Oh, now I see where I did a mistake :)

Comment: @RafferFlameline. Edit your post and explain your mistake. This will be useful for other users.